# No visible @interface for UITabBar setScrollEdgeAppearance

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, xcode12, xcode13

today i met with issue on Xcode 12. When i tried iOS 15 version of app i noticed that tabbar background changed. I solved this by adding this line of code

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
    [[UITabBar appearance] setScrollEdgeAppearance:tabBarAppearance.appearance];
}
```

But after I swapped back to Xcode 12 from Xcode 13 i got this issue.

> No visible @interface for 'UITabBar' declares the selector 'setScrollEdgeAppearance:'

Seems like Xcode12 bug for me but maybe i am wrong.

Edit: added if statement which was in code

Comment: It is available from iOS 13 only - `UINavigationBarAppearance *scrollEdgeAppearance UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0));`

Comment: Its more about xcode build failed. When i switch to xcode 13 everything works. And i need this line just for ios 15 but cant build it in xcode 12.

Comment: @Asperi `scrollEdgeAppearance` on `UINavigationBar` is not the same as `scrollEdgeAppearance` on `UITabBar`. `UINavigationBar` has had it since iOS 13.0. `UITabBar` had it added in iOS 15.0.

Comment: You'll want to do this compile time check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68941618/2108547

Comment: Ye i added empty function to UITabBar for xcode 12 and it solved the problem for me

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that worked for us in a swift-file:

```
#if swift(>=5.5) // Only run on Xcode version >= 13 (Swift 5.5 was shipped first with Xcode 13).
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        }
#endif
```

That snippet makes sure it is only compiled with Xcode Version > 13 and only runs for iOS 15. Swift 5.5 was introduced with Xcode 13.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because `scrollEdgeAppearance` was just a property of `UINavigationBar` for iOS < 15 versions. Since iOS 15 They've extended it to all others navigation bars

As per Apple doc:

> When running on apps that use iOS 14 or earlier, this property applies
> to navigation bars with large titles. In iOS 15, this property applies
> to all navigation bars.

Comment: Yes i understand its new property/method and i need it only for ios 15 version. But if i add the mentioned line xcode build fail because cant find the method. In xcode 13 everything works fine. Its strange for me that they dont support xcode 12 with that method.

Comment: That's because Xcode 12 doesn't support iOS 15

Answer (score 1):

It's only available in Xcode 13. So we did this to fix the issue and be able to compile on both Xcode 12 and 13:

```
#if __clang_major__ >= 13
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
    [[UITabBar appearance] setScrollEdgeAppearance:tabBarAppearance.appearance];
}
#endif
```